# How do I use fitnesse ActionFixture with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I tried to make an action fixture and it’s not working. (c# with Slim runner)

Basically it seems like it's trying to interpret it as a column fixture.

```
|!-Fitnesse.BuyActions-!      |
|Start|!-Fitnesse.BuyActions-!|
|check|total      |0.0        |
|enter|price      |12.00      |
|press|buy                    |
|check|total      |12.00      |
|enter|price      |100.00     |
|press|buy                    |
|check|total      |112.00     |



Fitnesse.BuyActions

Start
 Fitnesse.BuyActions
```

**check Method setStart not found in Fitnesse.BuyActions**

```
using fit;
namespace Fitnesse
{
    public class BuyActions : ActionFixture
    {
        public BuyActions()
            : base()
        {
            this.targetObject = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately FitNesse is not a popular or well-known topic here on SO. I monitor it because it's on my todo list of things to learn, but unfortunately I have no knowledge of it myself (yet). I wish you the best of luck in finding an answer, and definitely answer your own question if you figure it out, so that future people with the same problem can find this page as a reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionFixture does not work with Slim.  It is used with the Fit test system. See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests